# How sc.next() printed the value of the long that I entered inside try block

Tags: java, exception

```java
import java.util.*;

public class User {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {

        try
        {
            long x=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
            if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");
            if(x>=(Math.pow(-2,15)) && x<=(Math.pow(2,15))-1)System.out.println("* short");
            if(x>=(Math.pow(-2,31)) && x<=(Math.pow(2,31))-1)System.out.println("* int");
            if(x>=(Math.pow(-2,63)) && x<=(Math.pow(2,63))-1)System.out.println("* long");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }

    }
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

So I can't understand that how sc.next() printed the value that I entered in the sc.nextLong()

To know more about the problem view the link.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-datatypes/problem

Comment: Regarding the "asap": [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 1):

All `sc.next` variants (except `sc.nextLine()` which is weird) work in the exact same way: They fetch **the next** (hence the name) token from the stream of data, transforms it into what you asked for (`.nextInt()` transforms to an int, etc), and returns it. If the transformation cannot be done, for example, `"aaa"` cannot be transformed to an int, you get an exception.

Crucially, if a conversion cannot be performed, **the token is not consumed**.

In other words:

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner("aaa bbb 1234");
try {
  s.nextInt(); // crashes, 'aaa' is not an int
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  System.out.println("First token is not an int");
}

System.out.println(s.next()); // prints 'aaa'
```

In other words, the code you pasted 'works' by using the fact that if a `.nextLong()` calls doesn't return normally but throws an exception instead, the token is still there. `.next()` reads a token and just returns it without attempting to transform it into a long or whatnot.

Thus, your code has the following behaviour:

- If the token can be read fine but cannot be converted to a long, the code works as designed: That `sc.next()` call in the catch block will fetch the token and stuffs it into the exceptions' message.
- If the token *cannot* be read, for example because the file is on a USB disk and you pulled the USB stick out halfway through, the `nextLong()` call fails, goes to the catch block, which then **fails again**, and now you get an exception in your exception block. This is bad style.

Thus, does the code work? Barely. It's not nice code. The error message is unclear, and if you want to do this, you should be catching `InputMismatchException`, not all exceptions.